# Covering Anonymous Function Arguments in Unit Tests

Tags: javascript, react-native, mocha.js, chai, jestjs

I have multiple situations in code where we pass a function as an argument when creating an object (like so in onPress):

```
<Touchable
  onPress={() => Linking.openURL(formatUrl(url))} 
  noContainer={true}>      
    {children}
</Touchable>
```

When it comes down to it, this is a snippet in a larger component getting rendered. As it's not actually a method of the component, I'm not especially interested in testing it here - it will get tested as part of another component if needed.
[image: Code Coverage]
However, the code coverage report comes back with an indication that the function is uncovered.

Is there a way to satisfy this coverage - either by testing this function, or ignoring all functions passed in such a way (anonymously, as arguments)?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using Jest, you can set your Jest mock to call the argument that it receives, so:

```
const componentProps = {
  onPress: jest.fn(func => func());
}
```

So the mocked `onPress` function, in this case, will receive your anonymous function and call it. Coverage will show that the anonymous function was called.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I have a library function I am using that requires using an anonymous function within an anonymous function. Like: `api.get(inclusions => [inclusions.product.get(type => type.offers)])`. Any idea how I can get coverage for this second function?

Comment: Solved my own question, rubber ducky style. the mock will be `{ get: { fn => fn([{ product: { get: fn2 => fn2() }}])}}`. looks lovely.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd like to advise against exempting lines from coverage, especially if you're being paid to write this code and unit test it.

One thing I've found that works is to write a void function that calls your function with your desired arguments.

if you have:

```
onClick={ () => function(argument) }
```

and Jest isn't covering it, try:

```
const functionWithArgs = () => function(argument)
onClick={functionWithArgs}
```

I use this a lot for modals:

```
const [isModalOpen, setModalOpen] = React.useState(false)
const toggleModal = () => setModalOpen(!isModalOpen)
onClick={toggleModal}
```

But the same principle can be applied to a much more complex function. And it works!